# Can you explain how to convert this notation to a function to someone unfamiliar with group theory?

Tags: group-theory

While working on a project, I came across a paper (["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub)) that includes the definition $g ∈ $ on page 15, where $$ is the "tetrahedral group" ("a discrete subgroup of isometries $ ⊂ O(3)$"). The paper then uses $g(z)$ as a function with a complex input, where $z$ is "the local complex coordinate on the unit 2-sphere in $^3$ obtained by stereographic projection from the south pole".

***Is it possible to define an algebraic expression for $g(z)$ in a way that is understandable to a person with no background in group theory?***

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151408/discussion-on-question-by-lawton-can-you-explain-how-to-calculate-this-sum-to-so); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The group $O(3)$ is the group of isometric symmetries of the $2$-dimensional sphere $S^2$ in Euclidean 3-dimensional space. It has an index 2 subgroup of rotational symmetries denoted $SO(3)$.

When a regular tetrahedron $T$ is inscribed in $S^2$, the rotational symmetries of $T$ itself form a subgroup of $SO(3)$ with $12$ elements, called the tetrahedral group.

But, in order to write the elements of the tetrahedral group as functions of a complex variable, I have to guess a little bit at the intentions of the unknown author. (If this guess is wrong, then my whole answer is wrong).

My best guess is that the $2$-sphere $S^2$ is being transformed to the extended complex plane $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ using [stereographic projection](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Introduction_to_Groups_and_Geometries_(Lyons)/01%3A_Preliminaries/1.03%3A_Stereographic_projection). When this is done, the individual elements of $SO(3)$ can all be written as fractional linear transformations of $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$, meaning functions of the format
$$g(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers required to satisfy the normalization condition $ad-bc \ne 0$ (additional conditions are needed to pick out the case of a rotational symmetry of $S^2$ but that's beside the point).

It's common to write the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ in matrix format as $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, because composition of the functions $g(z)$ corresponds exactly to multiplication of the corresponding matrices, as long as you keep in mind that the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} ka & kb \\ kc & kd \end{pmatrix}$ represent the same function (for any nonzero complex number $k$). It is also common to require the more strict normalization $ad-bc=1$, as long as you keep in mind that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and its negative $\begin{pmatrix} -a & -b \\ -c & -d \end{pmatrix}$ represent the same function.

According to the paper of S. Ushiki entitled [Julia Sets with Polyhedral Symmetry](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eushiki/papers/PolySym/srpaa.pdf), the four vertices of the inscribed regular tetrahedron can be carefully chosen so that the stereographic transformation from $S^2$ to $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ takes those four vertices to the following four points in the complex plane $\mathbb C$, namely:
$$0, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \omega, \sqrt{2} \omega^2 \qquad\text{where }\qquad \omega = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \quad\text{hence}\quad \omega^3=1
$$
(and, of course, a real number $s$ -- such as $s=0$ or $s=\sqrt{2}$ --- is identified with the complex number $s+0i$).

And when the transformation is done in that manner, the $12$ elements of the tetrahedral subgroup of $O(3)$ correspond to the $12$ fractional linear transformations that permute the four points listed above. Writing those fractional linear transformations in matrix format, one gets the two matrices
$$M_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \omega & 0 \\ 0 & \omega^2 \end{pmatrix} \qquad M_2 \begin{pmatrix} - 1/\sqrt{3} i & \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} i \\ \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{3} i & 1 / \sqrt{3} i \end{pmatrix}
$$
as well as all the other matrices that can be obtained by multiplying these two in sequences (which is $24$ matrices altogether, occuring in $12$ negative pairs). In brief, those two matrices *generate* the tetrahedral subgroup, represented as a group of fractional linear transformations.

So for instance the first matrix above gives you the function $g_1(z)$ which simplifies to
$$g_1(z) = \omega^2 z = (-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i) z
$$
When applying this fractional linear transformation to the four points above, you can see that it cyclically permutes the three vertices $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}\omega$, $\sqrt{2}\omega^2$.

The second matrix above gives you the function $g_2(z)$ which simplifies to
$$g_2(z) = \frac{-z + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} z + 1}
$$
When applying this transformation to the four vertices listed above you can see that it transposes the two vertices $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and that it transposes the two vertices $\sqrt{2}\omega$ and $\sqrt{2}\omega^2$.

You might find it instructive to pick up a regular tetrahedron (for example a 4-sided gaming die) in order to visualize these symmetries.

If you want to see the formulas for all 12 of the different functions in the tetrahedral group, start multiplying $g_1$ and $g_2$ in all possible ways (or, for less work, multiply their matrices) in order to generate all the other elements of the tetrahedral group.

Comment: I added to my question a line from the paper explaining that the complex input of $g(z)$ is "the local complex coordinate on the unit 2-sphere in $^3$ obtained by stereographic projection from the south pole", if that affects your answer at all.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how to go from the two matrices you give to the full set of 12. Can you elaborate on that? I know matrix multiplication is non-commutative so the two orderings give two different results, but that only gives a total of four, not 12. I'm also a little confused about going from the matrix representation to the function representation. You say that $g_1(z) = ω z$, but by my interpretation it should be $g_1(z) = \frac{ω z + 0}{0 z + ω^2} = \frac{z}{ω}$. Am I missing something, or is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks for that first comment. In fact that confirms my guess.

Comment: For part of your second comment, you are right: using that $\omega^3=1$ it follows that $\frac{1}{\omega} = \omega^2$ and $g_1(z)=\omega^2 z$

Comment: For the other part of your second comment: you can multiply $M_1 \cdot M_1$, and $M_1 \cdot M_2$, and $M_2 \cdot M_1$, and $M_1 \cdot M_1 \cdot M_2$, and $M_1 \cdot M_2 \cdot M_1$, and $M_2 \cdot M_1 \cdot M_1$, and so on. After a while you will start seeing repetitions, and in the end you will get only 24 matrices in all, occurring in 12 inverse pairs.

Comment: I've been working on enumerating the matrix multiplications, and ignoring repeats I'm up to 14 total with none being obvious negatives of any others. Is there more to a matrix being "negative" than a simple sign change? Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Nope, just a sign change. You can check your work by comparing with rotational motions of a tetrahedron. Or even just by comparing with even permutations of a 4 element set (i.e. the vertices of the tetrahedron). Or, more specifically, by checking that each new matrix restricts to an even permutation of the 4 points $0$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}\omega$, $\sqrt{2}\omega^2$; in other words $g(0)$, $g(\sqrt{2})$, $g(\sqrt{2}\omega)$, $g(\sqrt{2}\omega^2)$ will be those same 4 points, re-ordered by some even permutation.

Comment: I figured out that some duplicates only become apparent when replacing the $ω$ character with its definition and simplifying, such as the pair $\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} ω^2 & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} ω^2 \\ \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} ω & \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} ω \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} ω^2 + \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} ω \\ -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} ω^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} & \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} ω \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Just to make sure I've got everything, is the identity matrix included as one of the twelve, or are there twelve matrices *in addition to* the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, the identity is one of the twelve. A bit of elementary group theory: from the definition of a group, every group has an identity element.

Comment: Your group even has another fancy name (up to isomorphism of groups): $A_4$, the alternating group on $4$ elements. Namely, the twelve elements of your group, when acting by permutations on the $4$ points $0$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}\omega$, $\sqrt{2}\omega^2$, comprise exactly the twelve even permutations of that set (including, of course, the identity permutation).

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answer, you can give a fairly straight-forward description of the tetrahedron on the Riemann sphere if you note that

$$
T=\{(1,1,1),(1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1)\}=\{(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3): \epsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\}, \epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3 =1\}
$$

form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron - although they lie on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$ rather than the unit sphere. Now stereographic projection from $C=(-1,-1,-1)$ takes a vector $v$ on the sphere to the vector $S(v)$ on the plane perpendicular to $C$ which is also on the line through $C$ and $v$. Thus $S(v) = t.v +(1-t)C$ where $t$ is determined by the condition that the dot product $S(v)\cdot C =0$. Thus $tv\cdot C +3(1-t)=0$, that is, $t = 3/(3-v\cdot C)$. It follows that for the projection of $(-1,-1,1)$ we must take $t= 3/(3-1)=3/2$, and hence the projection is $(-1,-1,2)$. Now rescaling by $1/\sqrt{3}$ we see that $(1,1,1)$ is sent to $0$, while the other 3 vertices are sent to the vectors
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-1,-1,2), \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-1,2,-1),\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(2,-1,-1).
$$

These are vectors of length $\sqrt{2}$ forming the vertices of an equilateral triangle, and hence can be rotated in the complex plane (identified with the plane $\{(x,y,z): x+y+z=0\}\subseteq \mathbb R^3$) so as to coincide with $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\omega, \sqrt{2}\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$