# How do I handle this single-variable function being called with two variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functions, differential-geometry, notation

As part of a personal project, I found the paper ["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub), which discusses deriving equations for a 3D surface I want to parameterize. However, despite my efforts to decipher the paper, I can't follow everything it is describing. The paper plays fast and loose with notation and relies on conventions I haven't encountered before. I have been unable to find other resources about the same surface that are easier to parse.

**I don't need a full understanding of all the involved concepts for the project I'm working on, I just need to know how to work the algebra to get the surface I want.**

## What I'm Trying to Understand

The key section of the paper for my purposes is **4.3 Discrete Symmetries**:

> #### 4.3 Discrete Symmetries
>
> Consider a discrete subgroup of isometries $G ⊂ O(3)$, and suppose that $r_0$ is the support function of a surface of constant width $w$.
>
> **Proposition 4.6:** The surface determined by the support function
> $$
> r(ξ, \bar{ξ}) = \frac{1}{\#G} \sum_{g ∈ G} r_0\bigl(g(ξ), g(\bar{ξ})\bigr),
> $$
> is a surface of constant width $w$ which is invariant under $G$.
>
> *Proof:* This follows from the fact that the antipodal map commutes with elements of $O(3)$. Q.E.D.
>
> Applying this approach to the case of $r_0$ being equal to the support function in Example 4.2 and $G$ being the tetrahedral group, we can construct closed convex surfaces of constant width with tetrahedral symmetry. The results are shown in Figure 5, where both a surface (left) and its focal set (right) are presented.
>
> [image: Figure 5]
> $$
> \text{Fɪɢᴜʀᴇ 5.}
> $$

[From a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4862288/530932) I know that with "$G$ being the tetrahedral group" we have $\frac{1}{\#G} = \frac{1}{12}$, and $g ∈ G$ refers to the following set of twelve functions in a complex variable $z$, where $U_n = e^{\frac{n}{3} ⋅ 2 π i}$ is the $n$th cube root of unity:

- $g_{01}(z) = U_0 ⋅ z = z$
- $g_{02}(z) = U_1 ⋅ z = -\frac{1 - \sqrt{3} i}{2} ⋅ z$
- $g_{03}(z) = U_2 ⋅ z = -\frac{1 + \sqrt{3} i}{2} ⋅ z$
- $g_{04}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_0 - 1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_0 ⋅ z + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - z}{\sqrt{2} z + 1}$
- $g_{05}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_1 - 1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_2 ⋅ z + 1} = \frac{(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6} i) + 2 ⋅ z}{(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} i) ⋅ z - 2}$
- $g_{06}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_2 - 1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ U_1 ⋅ z + 1} = \frac{(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} i) + 2 ⋅ z}{(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6} i) ⋅ z - 2}$
- $g_{07}(z) = U_1 ⋅ \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1} = -\frac{1 - \sqrt{3} i}{2} ⋅ \frac{\sqrt{2} - z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1}$
- $g_{08}(z) = U_2 ⋅ \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1} = -\frac{1 + \sqrt{3} i}{2} ⋅ \frac{\sqrt{2} - z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1}$
- $g_{09}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1 ⋅ U_1 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1 ⋅ U_2} = \frac{2 \sqrt{2} + (1 - \sqrt{3} i) ⋅ z}{2 \sqrt{2} ⋅ z - (1 + \sqrt{3} i)}$
- $g_{10}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1 ⋅ U_2 ⋅ z}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z + 1 ⋅ U_1} = \frac{2 \sqrt{2} + (1 + \sqrt{3} i) ⋅ z}{2 \sqrt{2} ⋅ z - (1 - \sqrt{3} i)}$
- $g_{11}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} + U_1 ⋅ (1 ⋅ z + \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z - U_2 ⋅ (1 - \sqrt{2} ⋅ z)} = \frac{-(z - \sqrt{2}) + \sqrt{3} i (z + \sqrt{2})}{ (1 + \sqrt{2} z) + \sqrt{3} i (1 - \sqrt{2} z)}$
- $g_{12}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2} + U_2 ⋅ (1 ⋅ z + \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ z - U_1 ⋅ (1 - \sqrt{2} ⋅ z)} = \frac{ (z - \sqrt{2}) + \sqrt{3} i (z + \sqrt{2})}{-(1 + \sqrt{2} z) + \sqrt{3} i (1 - \sqrt{2} z)}$

However, the sum in section 4.3 calls $r_0$ as a two-variable function $r_0\bigl(g(ξ), g(\bar{ξ})\bigr)$, yet it also states that $r_0$ is "equal to the support function in Example 4.2". The support function in question is a single-variable function in $R ∈ ℝ$ with three real parameters $a$, $b$, and $C$, giving a rotationally-symmetric surface of constant width $1 + 2 C$:
$$
r(R) = \frac{a + b R^2 + (3 - b) R^4 + (1 - a) R^6}{(1 + R^2)^3} + C
$$

## Central Question: How do I go from $r(R)$ to $r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$?

Section **2.2 Coordinates on**  defines $ξ$ thusly:

> Let $ξ$ be the local complex coordinate on the unit 2-sphere in $^3$ obtained by stereographic projection from the south pole. In terms of the standard spherical polar angles $(θ, φ)$ we have $ξ = \tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) e^{i φ}$.

Section **4.1 Rotational Symmetry** defines $R$ thusly:

> It is not hard to see that the map $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$ determining this line congruence satisfies $F = G(R) e^{i θ}$, where $G$ is a real function and $ξ = R e^{i θ}$.

(This means that $R_\text{§4} = \tan\left(\frac{θ_\text{§2}}{2}\right)$ and $θ_\text{§4} = φ_\text{§2}$.)

I've gone over this paper at least a dozen times now, and read online resources on differential geometry, and still can't figure out how I'm supposed to handle this. It makes sense that the rotationally-symmetric surface's support function is a one-variable function and the tetrahedrally-symmetric surface's is a two-variable function, but I don't see a natural way to convert the former into the latter.

## Supplemental

All the other definitions of "$r$" in the paper:

- 2.3 The Correspondence Space

  - **Definition 2.1:** The map $Φ :  × ℝ → ^3$ is defined to take $((ξ, η), r) ∈  × ℝ$ to the point in $^3$ on the oriented line $(ξ, η)$ that lies a distance $r$ from the point on the line closest to the origin (see the right of Figure 2).
- 2.4 Line Congruences

  - Given a line congruence $Σ ⊂ $, a map $r : Σ → ℝ$ determines a map $Σ → ^3$ by $(ξ, η) ↦ Φ\bigl((ξ, η), r(ξ, η)\bigr)$ for $(ξ, η) ∈ Σ$. In other words, we pick out one point on each line in the congruence (see Figure 3).
  - **Theorem 2.4:** A line congruence $\bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$ is orthogonal to a surface in $^3$ if and only if there is a real function $r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ satisfying $\frac{∂r}{∂\bar{ξ}} = \frac{2 F}{(1 + ξ \bar{ξ})^2}$. If there is a solution, there is a 1-parameter family generated by a real constant of integration. The function $r$ is the distance from the surface to the point on the normal line closest to the origin.
  - The surface can be reconstructed in $^3$ from this data be inserting $r = r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ and $η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ in equations (2.1). A change $r ↦ r + C$ moves the surface a distance $C$ along its normal to the “parallel” surface.
- 2.5 Focal Points of a Line Congruence

  - **Theorem 2.6:** The focal set of the parametric line congruence $Σ$ which is normal to a closed convex surface is given by $r = r_±(ξ, \bar{ξ}) = -ψ ± |σ|$, where the slopes ψ and σ are given by equation (2.2).
- 3.1 Oriented Normal lines

  - The set of oriented normal lines to $S$ forms a line congruence that can be parameterized by the direction of the normal. Thus the normals are given by a map $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$, and there exists a real function $r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ satisfying equation (2.3).
- 3.3 Constant Width Surfaces with Rational Support

  - **Definition 3.7:** A closed convex surface has *rational support* if the support function is of the form $r = \frac{P(ξ, \bar{ξ})}{Q(ξ, \bar{ξ})}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are real-valued polynomials.
- 4.1 Rotational Symmetry

  - **Proposition 4.2:** The focal set of the oriented normals to a convex, rotationally symmetric surface with support function $r = r(R)$ is given by the surface $z = \frac{1}{2} \left(-R (1 + R^2) \frac{d^2 r}{d R^2} + (1 - 3 R^2) \frac{d r}{d R}\right) e^{i θ}$, $t = \frac{1}{4} \left(-(1 - R^4) \frac{d^2 r}{d R^2} - 2 R (3 - R^2) \frac{d r}{d R}\right)$, and the line $z = 0$, $t = -\frac{(1 + R^2)^2}{4 R} \frac{d r}{d R}$, where $z = x^1 + i x^2$ and $t = x^3$, for standard coordinates $(x^1, x^2, x^3)$ on Euclidean 3-space.
  - **Proposition 4.3:** The cusps on the focal set of the oriented normals to a convex, rotationally symmetric surface with support function $r = r(R)$ are solutions of the equation $(1 + R^2) \frac{d^3 r}{d R^3} + 6 R \frac{d^2 r}{d R^2} + 6 \frac{d r}{d R} = 0$.

## Background

A ***Surface of Constant Width*** is a 3D surface with the special property that any two parallel planes which are tangent to it are always a constant distance apart, no matter the relative rotations of the surface and paired-planes. I want to derive a trio of parametric equations $\bigl(X(u, v), Y(u, v), Z(u, v)\bigr)$ which together give a surface with the following properties:

- has a constant width of $w = S + 2 A$, where $S$ is a positive real number, $A$ is a non-negative real number and the radius of the smallest osculating circle on the surface, and $S + A$ is the radius of the largest osculating circle on the surface;
- both $u$ and $v$ have finite lower and upper bounds; and
- has full tetrahedral symmetry, down to the points generated on the surface with interpolation of $u$ and $v$;
- is $G^∞$-smooth for positive values of $S$ and $A$ (meaning the surface, curvature, derivative of curvature, second derivative of curvature, and so on are all continuous at all points on the surface).

Comment: $r_0$ is a function on a surface, so having 2 arguments seems reasonable to me.  Where is $r_0$ defined in the paper with only 1 variable?

Comment: Every $r(-)$ function I see in that paper has two arguments.

Comment: The only time in that paper that functions like $r$ are given single arguments is when the underlying surface has rotational symmetry.

Comment: @Randall Proposition 4.6 (bottom of page 15) gives the sum I reference, and just a bit farther down says "Applying this approach to the case of $r_0$ being equal to the support
function in Example 4.2 ...". The support function in Example 4.2 is the single-variable function I reference.

Comment: Isn't that function $r$ a function of the two variables $a$, $b$ or am I misreading?

Comment: @Randall $a$ and $b$ are parameters that, together with $c$, control the shape and position of the shape generated from the support function. At least, I implemented it in GeoGebra and it works perfectly that way. The whole of Section 4 is based around functions of a single variable called $R$.

Comment: It kinda looks like they are re-parametrizating the functions implicitly. Like, suppose you had an $f(x,y)$, and you showed its value only depended on $s=x+y$, so you started writing it as $f(s)$. If that's the case I'd say it was poor exposition, but it happens.

Comment: @JonathanZ Do you see such a dependence in the paper? I'm not seeing one...

Comment: Yeah, that's only an analogy. A little bit above the equation you've asked about I see them discussing the radially symmetric case, and they write (something like) $\xi = Re^{i\theta}$, and then they start treating $r(-)$ as a function of $R$. I think your equation isn't in the "assume radially symmetric" part, but that's an example where they are similarly loose about notation, which made me think they might be doing something similar. My comment isn't a complete explanation, just a suggestion as to what to look for.