# Can the construction of this 2D Curve of Constant Width be adapted to a 3D Surface of Constant Width?

Tags: differential-geometry, solid-geometry, smooth-functions

A [Surface of Constant Width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_constant_width) is a 3D surface with the special property that any two parallel planes which are tangent to it are always a constant distance apart, no matter the relative rotations of the surface and paired-planes. I want to construct a trio of parametric equations $\bigl(X(u, v), Y(u, v), Z(u, v)\bigr)$ that give a surface with the following properties:

- has a constant width of $S + 2 A$, where $S$ and $A$ are non-negative real numbers, $A$ is the radius of the smallest [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) on the surface, and $S + A$ is the radius of the largest osculating circle on the surface;
- has full tetrahedral symmetry;
- is $G^∞$-smooth for positive values of $S$ and $A$ and finite values of $u$ and $v$, meaning the surface, curvature, derivative of curvature, second derivative of curvature, and so-on are all continuous in all directions at all points on the surface; and
- linear-step interpolation between the minimum and maximum values for $u$ and $v$ produces 3D points with a tetrahedrally-symmetrical arrangement and constant (or nearly-constant) angles between the normal-vectors of neighboring points (meaning points are closer together in highly-curved areas of the surface, and farther apart in less-curved areas of the surface).

I was able to get exactly what I wanted in ***two dimensions*** with the paper ["A Polynomial Curve of Constant Width" by Stanley Rabinowitz](http://stanleyrabinowitz.com/download/polynomialconstantwidth.pdf). Based on that paper, we can define the functions

$$
p(t) = \left(1 + \frac{\cos(n × t)}{n^2 - 1}\right) × \frac{S}{2} + A
$$
$$
X(t) = \cos(t) × p(t) - \sin(t) × p'(t)
$$
$$
Y(t) = \sin(t) × p(t) + \cos(t) × p'(t)
$$

where $S$ is a positive real number, $A$ is a non-negative real number and the radius of the smallest osculating circle on the curve, $S + A$ is the radius of the largest osculating circle on the curve, and $n$ is an odd integer greater than 2.

When plotted as the parametric curve $C(t) = \bigl(X(t), Y(t)\bigr)$ with $0 ≤ t < 2 π$, these generate a smoothed-out version of a regular $n$-sided [Reuleaux polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_polygon) with side-length $S$ and corner-radius $A$, which is also (for positive $A$) $G^∞$-smooth at all points. Additionally, when sampling the curve at parameter values with a step-size of $Δt = \frac{2 π}{n k}$ for integer $k$, the normal-vectors of adjacent sample-points have angles that differ by a constant $\frac{2 π}{n k}$ radians, and the arrangement of the sample-points has full $n$-gon dihedral symmetry.

[image: Smooth Triangular Curve of Constant Width]

I've tried to figure out how to adapt the methods in Rabinowitz's paper to three dimensions, but without success.

***How do I construct such an adaptation, for the constraints I have specified?***

I did find the paper ["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub), which includes a figure on page 16 that depicts the surface I want to parameterize, and discusses doing the exact 2D-to-3D conversion I want. However, despite my efforts to decipher this paper, I can't follow what it is describing, as the key part of the paper hinges on [using a function defined with a single variable as a function of two variables, and I can't figure out how to handle that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862905/how-do-i-handle-this-single-variable-function-being-called-with-two-variables).

Comment: I doubt a construction of a constant width curve can be extended to that of a constant width surface. I recall that Robert Bryant provided a pretty explicit way to find an example of a constant width surface. Were you not able to to use that?

Comment: @Deane I have not been able to adapt Robert Bryant's method to my purposes, no. The paper I link in the last paragraph of this question claims to extend the 2D curve to the 3D surface I want, so it should be possible, I just can't follow it.

Comment: Are you familiar with using spherical coordinates for parameterizing a convex surface that contains the origin?

Comment: @Deane Roughly, yes.

Comment: Here's what little I can offer: A standard way to specify a convex body is to say what its support function is. If you can provide this function for one of the examples, I can explain how to draw the body. I suggest looking at Bryant's example carefully. I think he might have written down an explicit formula for the support function.

Comment: @Deane The 2D support function in this question is $p(t)$, as I understand it. The 3D support function is what I'm trying to figure out. The paper I link at the end of this question says to use the same support function from their 2D case in their 3D case, but I can't figure out how to use the single-variable 2D function in the dual-variable 3D case. Meanwhile, Bryant's support function produced undesirable vertex distributions and I couldn't find a way to adjust it to fix that.

Comment: Could you provide the formula for Bryant's support function? How are you plotting the surface using the support function?

Comment: Bryant's comment:
"Here is a simple formula for the parametrization: For $u=(x,y,z)\in S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e., $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$) and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ any constant, set
$$b(u) = (1-2cxyz)\bigl(x,y,z\bigr) + c\bigl(yz,xz,xy\bigr).$$
The mappping $b:S^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ then has its image a convex surface of constant breadth when $|c|$ is sufficiently small. Now choose your favorite parametrization of $S^2$ and compose with $b$. This gives a parametrization of a surface of constant breadth equal to 2 that has tetrahedral symmetry."

Comment: @Deane I tried using the standard paramterization of spherical coordinates $(θ, φ)$, as well as some simple modifications to try and control the vertex distribution, but couldn't find a nice arrangement.

Comment: I tried plotting Bryant's example using Python. Go to https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/deaneyang/ConstantWidth.git/HEAD and double click on ConstantWidth.ipynb. You can also try other values of c. c=1.0 also generated a reasonable looking surface, but c=2.0 did not. I do not know how to improve or rotate this image.

Comment: @Deane I implemented Bryant's surface in GeoGebra (https://www.ztlawton.com/constant-width-bryant-surface.html). You can rotate the 3D view and use sliders to adjust the parameters. As-is, this parameterization of the surface doesn't meet two of the four required properties from my question: I haven't figured out how to convert the $r$ and $c$ parameters to $S$ and $A$, and the point distribution on the surface is not tetrahedrally-symmetric.

Comment: In principal, you can calculate $S$ and $A$ from the formula above. But you or someone else will have to do that. The tetrahedral symmetry can be seen from the fact that the formula is invariant under permutation of the coordinates. So you can the following: Find a parameterization of one side of the regular tetrahedron.  Use it to plot one "side" of the constant width surface. You can now plot the other sides using the same parameterization but with the coordinates permuted. This results in a point distribution with the tetrahedral symmetry.